# Drivers for Spansion s25hx512 Flash

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, u-boot, barebox

Does anyone have a working (successfully) configuration for Spansion s25hs512t or other similar (s25hsxxx / s25hlxxx) NOR Flash with u-boot and barebox.

I have tried on their official forum but have no working drivers / hints for making it work with 2021.x versions of u-boot and barebox (latest they have is 2018).

Also linking previous Question on the problem I am having with making it work

- with u-boot-fslc (2021.04+fslc) & barebox (2021.08.0) [Write failing without error on QSPI (Spansion s25hs512t) - u-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111195/write-failing-without-error-on-qspi-spansion-s25hs512t-u-boot)
- With u-boot (Master) [Spansion S25HS512T NOR Flash not working on linux or u-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68912054/spansion-s25hs512t-nor-flash-not-working-on-linux-or-u-boot). Ignore Linux bit

If anyone can share how they have managed to get it work it would be immense help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has partly been addressed at [Spansion S25HS512T NOR Flash not working on linux or u-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68912054/spansion-s25hs512t-nor-flash-not-working-on-linux-or-u-boot)

There are still problems but it is a start.

Support under barebox may not yet be functioning

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).